# accessing a pinia store in multiple components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

this is my first time using pinia and I am trying to implement a shoppingcart store. I have a page where I add items to my shoppingcart store and another where I want to display them, however when I navigate to the shoppingcart page (where I want to display them) my state is completely empty. It was my understanding of pinia that my state would carry over from one page to another. I am using vue3

My store definition

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const shoppingCartStore = defineStore({
  id: "shoppingCart",
  state: () => ({
    products: {},
    productData: {},
    totalPrice: 0.0,
    numberOfProducts: 0
  }),
  actions: ... (to add and remove items from the store)
    addProduct(product,amount) {
      if (product.priceid in this.products){
        this.products[product.priceid] += amount
      }
      else{
        this.products[product.priceid] = amount
        this.productData[product.priceid] = product
      }
    }
  },
});
```

The page where I add items to my shoppingcart:

```js
import { shoppingCartStore } from '@/stores/shoppingCart.js'
export default {
    setup(){
        const shoppingCart = shoppingCartStore()
        return { shoppingCart }
    },
...
// this is how I add items to my shoppingcart (it is in a function I just left all the other code out for simplicity
this.shoppingCart.addProduct(product,1) 
...
```

The page where I want to display my shoppingcart:

```js
import { shoppingCartStore } from '@/stores/shoppingCart.js'

export default {
    setup(){
        const shoppingCart = shoppingCartStore()
        return { shoppingCart }
    },
```

main.js (this is how I instantiate Pinia)

```js
...
let pinia = createPinia();

app.use(pinia);
...
```

When I was looking this error up I found this [github discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/927) where someone explains that it should work like I am using it but for me it doesn't.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Generally there's no such problem. It could be race condition, or the loss of reactivity, or else on your side. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. "this is how I add items to my shoppingcart" - you use composition api, there is supposed to be no this.shoppingCart

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I changed my function and placed it in the setup() function removing the "this.shoppingCart". I was able to fix my issue by removing the async modifier of my function which I had forgotten to remove